# Pass geometry package with the "showframe" option by command line

Tags: compiling, framed

I have this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe,a4paper}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to remove the `geometry` stuff from the file and pass it by command line. I mean something like:

```
latex "\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[pass]{geometry}\geometry{showframe,a4paper}}\
\input{myfile.tex}"
```

As it is, it doesn't work (the frame isn't added). Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Firstly, load `etoolbox`
- Then load and config `geometry` inside `\AtEndPreamble{...}`

```
pdflatex -jobname=myfile '\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage[pass]{geometry}\geometry{showframe, a4paper}}\input{myfile}'
```