# Highlight < ( ¡ ) and > (¿) in text mode

Tags: fonts

I need a way to ease the spotting of `<` and `>` used in `text-mode` (I get `¡` and `¿` in the `.pdf` file).

Is there a way to highlight these symbols in the `.pdf` file? I mean `¡` and `¿`.

(I'm not allowed to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

Comment: how can you not be allowed to use T1? you can use `\showoutput` then search the log for lines ending in `space <`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The journals I work for have OT1 by default. I tried `\showoutput` but it takes ages to compile... I could use emacs to spot these cases but i'd prefer to "see" them in the `.pdf` file.

Comment: Even for English, OT1 makes very little sense: < turning in to ¡ for example:-) For any other language it's pretty much a disaster. You could try making < active with `\ifmmode normal < else $<$\fi` then you wouldn't get ¡  but something is bound to break

Comment: The use of OT1 is not my choice. I don't want to avoid the problem but to "see" it so I can fix it using, e.g. $<$, when needed. I'd really need, if possible, to highlight these symbols in the .pdf files.

Comment: sure as I started the comment I was going to suggest making the character red  in text mode but if you can do that, you could use $<$  it is the same test either way

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to search the pdf file for `¡`?

Comment: @campa I'd prefer a "passive" way to approach this issue. I don't want to actively search for these characters but so "see" them it they are present. To do so I would pass some "highlighters" to the latex engine. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553938/33634

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no other way than to make `<` and `>` active so they print something evident when used in text mode and the standard symbols in math mode. Of course any `<` or `>` comparison in the context of `\ifnum` (or derived) that are not buried in macros defined in the preamble will die horribly.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`< \lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{\ifmmode<\else OUCH!`\fi}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`> \lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{\ifmmode>\else OUCH?`\fi}%
  \catcode`>=\active
  \catcode`<=\active
}

\begin{document}

$a<b$ $a>b$

<>

$\left<x\right>$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!